# Trying to replace all strings in an array of length > 3 with a '_______'

Tags: python

I am turning paragraphs into arrays so that I can replace each word in the array into a blank space if it of length greater than 3.

I can create the array easily. I'm now stuck on making it equal to the blank, why isn't equating enough?

```
f = open('save.txt', 'r')

import re

with open("save.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        newline = re.sub("[^\w]", " ",  line).split()
        for i in newline:
            if len(i) > 3:
                i == '________'
```

Comment: It actually will do something different, since `=` is definitely something completely different from `==` - however, without sharing an example for `save.txt`, it's impossible to say why you see no results. However - since you're just assigning a value to `i` and not doing anything with it, what exactly did you expect to see?

Comment: FYI, `[^\w]` can be simplified to `\W`. You should also use a raw string for regular expressions.

Comment: show us what save.txt looks like and what you expect the outcome to be

Comment: Are you trying to create a new file or update the existing one as well?

Comment: Do you even need to use a regex? Can be done in a comprehension `newline = ["________" if len(w) > 3 else w for w in newline.split()]`

Comment: @barmar Do you know why I cannot write a variable into the ```\W```, in place of the number 4, so I can change this number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to turn the line into an array to do this, you can use a regular expression to match words longer than 3 characters, and `re.sub()` will replace them with the placeholder.

```
newline = re.sub(r'\w{4,}', '________', line)
```

Comment: There's also `re.sub(r"\w{4,}", lambda x: "_" * len(x.group()), line)` if OP wants the underscore to be the same as the original word length.

Comment: @ggorlen You're both Kings.

Comment: @barmar is it possible to put this into a function, so I can have the parameter be inside the ```\w{4,}``` instead of 4. I've tried to do this but it acts as if I've done nothing.

Comment: You can construct the regexp dynamically: `regexp = r'\w{' + str(size) + ',}'`

Answer (score 1):

`i == '________'` means "Test if `i` is equal to `'________'`". You don't use the result (`True` or `False`) so it does nothing.

Even `i = '________'` (`=` for assignment) wouldn't help, because the `i` name is an *alias* of the `str` stored in the `list`; rebinding the name to `'________'` doesn't change the value in the `list`. If you want to change the `list`, you either make a new `list` with the correct values, or you iterate [using `enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to get the index to assign back to, changing:

```
    for i in newline:
        if len(i) > 3:
            i == '________'
```

to something like:

```
    for i, word in enumerate(newline):
        if len(word) > 3:
            newline[i] = '________'
```

where `i` now means the index in `newline` (which is the more common usage for `i`), and `word` aliases the value originally stored at that index. By keeping the index, you can assign back to it, replacing the value in the `list` with the desired placeholder.

The new `list` solution would be done with a `list` comprehension, e.g.:

```
newline = re.sub("[^\w]", " ",  line).split()  # Unchanged from original code

# Build new list and rebind newline to new list
newline = ['________' if len(word) > 3 else word for word in newline]
```

Comment: It's also not saving `newline` anywhere.

Comment: @Barmar: True. I guess I'm assuming the `newline` gets used later on in some useful way.